# Eclipse Plugin Preference List with Checkboxes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an Eclipse Plugin and I have a preference page and I need to get a ListFieldEditor with a check box in each row. Like so

[image: Preference Page]

I have found many examples of this throughout Eclipse but no tutorials or code on how to make it or access the data it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no `FieldEditor` that will provide the wanted table. This you will have to code yourself. See `org.eclipse.ui.internal.net.ProxyPreferencePage` for this particular version.